# Add ID column to a query result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my first time asking a question about T-SQL and I am a beginner with it. I have a SQL query which consists of two CTE's filtered down to less than 10 rows. I am using a SUM statement to get a running total:

```
Sum(Diff) OVER(ORDER BY DateAdded) AS Summary
```

`DateAdded` has the same value for several rows. Therefore, it does not give me a running total for each row. I need to create a field that simply counts the number of rows (similar to a PK in a DB table) so I can use it for my `ORDER BY` clause. If my understanding is correct, this is what I need to do to make it work. How can I add an enumerated column to the query result set? Please note, I do not want to `ALTER` a table, just add a column to the query result. I hope what I wrote is clear. Thank you!

Comment: Count and Sum are two very different things

Comment: "a field that simply counts the number of rows (similar to a PK in a DB table)" -- hmm, that's not the definition of a key.

Comment: I understand. I wasn't trying to define a PK, per say. I was just using it to illustrate what the output should look like. Sorry!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using `count()` or `sum()` you can use [row_number()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) which will give a distinct row number, starting at 1, for each row in your result set:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dateAdded) as Summary
```

Comment: If he's trying to get a running total that would require nested CTEs so that he can get the `ROW_NUMBER` first and then use that in the `ORDER BY` of his next windowed aggregate (`SUM` in this case).

Comment: OP doesn't say they want a running total, merely that they want a "a field that simply counts the number of rows". OP was using `SUM()` to do that, but I'm not assuming that `Sum()` is literally what was wanted.

Comment: @TomH is correct in understanding what I want (maybe I wasn't clear, I apologize). `ROW_NUMBER()` did give me what I was looking for (an additional enumerated column) for use in my running total and I will use that.

Comment: this syntax also works with MySql

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Result TABLE
(
    DT DATETIME
)
INSERT INTO @Result SELECT '1 Jan 1900'
INSERT INTO @Result SELECT '1 Jan 1900'

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DT DESC) AS "Row Number", DT
FROM @Result
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe that you can just add `NEWID()` to your `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT SUM(diff) OVER (ORDER BY DateAdded, NEWID()) AS Summary
```

Comment: @onedaywhen He said a lot of things. I answered the actual problem, not the specific question at the end of his post. That tends to be more useful in my experience, rather than being pedantic.

Comment: @Brian If you're trying to preserve a specific row order then you should have an `ORDER BY` in your query (not just the `OVER` clause). This won't affect that in any way.